# Is there any difference between restrictive and non-restrictive clauses, and defining and non-defining clauses?

Tags: grammar, difference, grammaticality-in-context, relative-clauses

Are these the same things called differently or not?

Restrictive clause:

> The person who taught the ceramics class is a friend of my mother’s.

Non-restrictive clause:

> Every journalist has a novel in him, which is an excellent place for it.

Defining clause:

> There are now only two schools in the area that actually teach Latin.

Non-defining clause:

> Doctors use the testing kit for regular screening for lung and stomach cancers, which account for 70% of cancers treated in the western world.

What is the difference between these two types of clauses  (restrictive and non-restrictive, and defining and non-defining)?

Comment: According to Wikipedia *Restrictive relative clauses are also called integrated relative clauses, **defining relative clauses**, or identifying relative clauses. Conversely, non-restrictive relative clauses are called supplementary, appositive, **non-defining** or non-identifying relative clauses.* So I think it is just a difference in terminology used by different English resources.

Comment: There's no difference. 'Defining' and 'restrictive' have the same meaning when talking of clauses. Some modern grammars don't use those terms at all, but call them more accurately 'integrated' (and 'supplementary' for the non-defining/restrictive type).

Comment: Thank you for explaining, I got rather confused when I learnt about restrictive and non-restrictive clauses. Now everything is clear to me.